# BATCH- echo % (print an percent sign)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

In my program i made it so that it shows 20% or 2% but the percent signs don't show. Any way you to display the percentage symbol?

(This is for minimal character limit don't bother looking down here)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Doubling the percent sign will print one percent sign:

```
echo %%
```

Comment: Does not work, my output from `echo %%` is `%%`. Instead, `^%` does in fact work.